# Rubocop error on Rspec/DescribeClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

I've recently updated to the most recent version of Rubocop (0.51) due to a bug in the previos version, but now it marks the following as error:

```
spec/controllers/loans_controller_spec.rb:3:10: C: RSpec/DescribeClass: The first argument to describe should be the class or module being tested.
describe LoansController do
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the way I've been doing it since forever, and is in fact the class I want to test.

The same is happening with all files in my spec folder. They all have the correspondent class name.

Comment: It sounds like that cop is broken. I would skip it for the time being and raise an issue on github.

Comment: The rspec cops are also provided by [`rubocop-rspec`](https://github.com/backus/rubocop-rspec) and not the core rubocop gem. The latest version is 1.20.1.

Comment: I do have the last version of rubocop-rspec aswell. I think I will just ignore it for the moment.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Is the example omitting some other code?

Comment: I seem to have been mistaken, and the rubocop-rspec version was not the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix the erro by updating rubocop-rspec version.

It was version 1.10 and updated it to 1.20.1 the error did not show again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify that the class you are testing is a controller, after the reference to the class you must specify what kind of class it is. In your case it would be `:type => :controller`

Example:

```
RSpec.describe LoansController, :type => :controller do
end
```

for more information you can visit the following link [Rspec Controllers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs)